# Using currval for database update reference

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**1) First query**

```
INSERT INTO stay_in_touch_contacts (id, facebook, twitter, instagram, external_contact) VALUES (nextval(seq_stay_in_touch_contacts), 'somelink', 'somelink', 'someling', 'somelink');
```

**2) Second query**

```
Update users SET stay_in_touch_contacts_id=currval('seq_stay_in_touch_id') WHERE ...;
```

They goes one by one in my code.

***Is it possible that this query cause unexpected column reference when database will be used simultaneously?
How to avoid it?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currval()` is session specific.

If a separate session increments your sequence, `currval()` will continue to return your expected value and the update statement won't use a wrong value for `stay_in_touch_contacts_id`

I hope I understood the question correctly.